# Creating a structured category list in F#

Tags: f#

This takes a list of categories and organizes them into a tree-type structure based on their `parentId`.  This code works, but is obviously a little over-complicated. How can I optimize it?

```
type ValidString = | ValidString of string | NotValid

type CategoryStructure = {
    Id: ValidString;
    ParentId: ValidString;
    Name: ValidString;
    Abbreviation: ValidString;
    Description: ValidString;
    SapId: ValidString;
    Section: ValidString;
    SectionPosition: ValidString
}

type DynamicCategories = {
    Category: CategoryStructure;
    SubCategories: seq<DynamicCategories>
}

let rec private structureCategories (fullList: CategoryStructure list) 
    (list: CategoryStructure list)  =

    List.fold (fun acc elem -> 


                    // get all categories and details
                    let categories = fullList
                    let mainAcc =
                        [

                            for row in categories do
                                if row = elem
                                then
                                    let subs =  
                                        List.fold (fun acc' elem' ->

                                                    if row.Id = elem'.ParentStructureId
                                                    then
                                                        let modifiedList = elem' :: List.empty<CategoryStructure>
                                                        let foundSubCategory = 
                                                            {
                                                                Category = elem';
                                                                SubCategories = structureCategories fullList modifiedList |> Seq.ofList
                                                            }
                                                        foundSubCategory :: acc'
                                                    else acc'

                                                    ) List.empty<DynamicCategories> categories
                                        |> Seq.ofList        
                                    yield{
                                        Category = elem;
                                        SubCategories = subs
                                    }


                        ]

                    mainAcc @ acc
                    ) List.empty<DynamicCategories> list

// get the initial parent categories and then call the above code to finish the organizing the list
let getStructuredCategories () =

        let categories = allCategoriesAndDetails () |> List.ofSeq
        [
            for row in categories do
                if row.ParentStructureId = NotValid
                then yield row
        ] |> structureCategories categories |> Seq.ofList
```

Comment: why not use `Seq.fold` instead of `List.fold |> Seq.ofList?`

Comment: What's the added benefit here for seq.fold. I'm new to f# so there is no particular strategy here other than to just get it initially working. That's why I'm here now, to see how to make this more efficient.

Comment: Its more that your just mixing Lists and Seqs and its not clear why.

Comment: In general, it seems like you do lots of conversions between List and Seq.  For example the last function could be `let ...() = let t = allcateogriesanddetails(); t |> List.Filter (fun t -> t.ParentStructureID=NotValid) |> StructureCategories categories`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optimized version that I have discovered:

```
let getStructuredCategories ()  =

let fullList = allCategoriesAndDetails () 

let parentList () =
    allCategoriesAndDetails ()
    |> Seq.filter (fun p -> p.ParentStructureId = NotValid)

let rec toTree (fullList': seq<CategoryStructure>) (parent: CategoryStructure) =

    fullList'
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.ParentStructureId = parent.Id)
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
                    {
                        Category = x;
                        SubCategories =
                            toTree fullList' x
                    })
seq {
    for row in parentList () do
    yield {

        Category = row;
        SubCategories = toTree fullList row    
    }

}
```

Can someone else do better?

Comment: The last `seq` can be replaced with `parentList() |> Seq.map (fun t -> Category=t;SubCategories=toTree fillList row`

Comment: `filter |> map` can be replaced by `choose`